# Arg assigning using for-switch

Tags: c#, arrays, arguments, switch-statement

so I'm writing a program that reads in parameters from a config file.

I know I could read them into an array, then assign each variable its corresponding element from the array. Then I thought, why not just assign them as I read them in, I know what order they will be read in beforehand. So I put a switch in a for loop and assigned each variable based on the index as I read it in, a simplified version is shown below.

```
private void parseFile(string fileName)
        {
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader( fileName );
            for (int i = 0; (line = file.ReadLine()) != null;  ) {
                line = line.Trim();
                //Comments are made by surrounding string in []
                if (line[0] == '[' && line[line.Length - 1] == ']') { continue; }

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        firstVar = line;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        secondVar = line;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ThirdVar = line;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new MissingFieldException( "Error in structure of file with variable " + line );
                }
                ++i;
            }
       }
```

After writing it out, however, it looked really ugly, and I thought there must be a better way.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way?
2. If so, what is it?
3. If not, is it preferable to read into an array and assign over, or use the for-switch structure and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general I would say switching to XML and losing the dependency or order completely would be a better way

Comment: Thats a good idea, I think I'll switch to XML

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring three separate variables for each line I would store them in a `List` or `Array.`You can do that using linq easily:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path")
            .Where(line => !line.StartsWith("[") && 
                           !line.EndsWith("]"))
            .ToList();
```

If you still need to assign each line to separate variables you can still do it:

```
if(lines.Count >= 3) 
{
    var firstVar = lines[0];
    var secondVar = lines[1];
    var thirdVar = lines[2];
}
```

Comment: Right, but why is this preferable to the for-switch method, since I do need to assign each variable out, I'll have to loop over each argument twice, where a switch, though ugly in a for loop, is faster.

Comment: because this is shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a dictionary - it's set up for key/value pairs. Use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["firstVar"] = "whatever your first line is";
dict["secondVar"] = "second line";
```

The first string is your key and the second string is your value. So "firstVar" would be whatever you wanted your first variable to be called, "secondVar" your second, etc. These values don't need to be explicit so you can do something like this...

```
string key = "Whatever you're using to determine your key names";
dict[key] = line;
```

This way you don't have to set up individual variables for each thing you're trying to store. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx